# Grails - Transactional Spring noRollbackFor not working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-transactions

I'm using a grails 1.3.7 and have the following code:

Grails service:

```
class MyClass {
   static transactional = true

  @Transactional(noRollbackFor = MyException.class)
  public MyObject myMethod(Map map1, Boolean bl1 = false) throws MyException {
   //codes
     if(...){
        throw new MyException("msg")
     }
}
```

MyException:

```
class MyException extends Exception{

 def errors = []

MyException(errors){
    super(errors.toString())
    this.errors = errors
}
```

}

When code throws an MyException, I catch the following error: **Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only**

Ps. If I change static transactional = true the error not occurs.

Any Idea?

Comment: Is MyClass Spring managed?

Comment: Assuming `MyClass` is a grails service, is your method calling any other transactional methods? If so, the `noRollbackFor` can get lost.

Comment: The method call others domain methods.

Comment: What @codelark and I are asking is whether MyClass is a Grails service (or otherwise a Spring managed service)? If not, it will not automatically take part in a transaction.

Comment: The Grails service "MyClass" is called by controller.

Answer (score 0):

I you use annotations, you should set

`static transactional=false`

i.e. invalidate grails' transactional proxy, so that there is no overlap with the proxy from spring AOP

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[FooException, BarException])
def doSomething(...) {
     ...
}
```

But remember, if you use transactional annotations, grails automatic transactions does not work in the service where you place that it. You need to set:

```
@Transactional
class myService(...) {
     static transactional = false
     ...
}
```